# Crystal Reports - Stored Procedure Syntax Question

Tags: crystal-reports

When I drag a field from my stored procedure onto a formula (Crystal Reports 11), I get something like this:

```
{sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.ST0405_Ext}
```

What does the "1." represent?

I hope it refers to the table number... because I'd like to return two tables from the stored procedure and be able to access both from a report.

Thanks

Comment: does your SP return 2 tables? Also, does the 1st table have this field named "ST0405_Ext"? If so, you could be right in your assumption.

Comment: It does not currently return 2 tables. I would like to modify it to return 2 tables. I'm curious if anybody knows what this 1. represents. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the semicolon one (";1") represents if the sp is active or not in the database.

I opened a report and connected to a datasource I frequently use and all of the sp's have ";1" except for 2 sp's which have ";0". Those sp's are old sp's which were deleted and do not show in the SQL Server Management Studio.

I don't believe that multiple tables can be pulled into a Crystal Report from an sp. When I just tried it on my system Crystal Reports closed out.